# how to find the actual ID except the R.id?

Tags: android, r.java-file

i have a table in my layout, in my onClick function, i have this code:

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();  
dataBundle.putInt("id", 4);
dataBundle.putString("timeday", v.getId());
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ir.udk.gcs.ViewCTRL.class);
intent.putExtras(dataBundle); 
startActivity(intent);
```

which in line 3, v.getid() returns an int number, but i want the id that i choose in my layout to be returnd as string, 
my table cels IDs in layout are something like = "sh00", "sh01", "sh02" and...

I want Them, to be puted in my  dataBundle, not their int id in R file. Any suggestions?

Comment: i don't think you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());
```

should do it. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName(int)) you can find the documentation